# Getting started with OpenGL ES 2.0 PowerVR SDK

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl-es-2.0

I am looking for some help getting started with OpenGL ES 2.0 on my Pandaboard (GPU:PowerVR). My Problem is that my application uses OpenCV to perfom some image processing and image viewing. Unfortunatley image viewing with OpenCV is very slow. So I decided to uses OpenGL ES 2.0 to view my images. I downloaded PowerVR Insider Legacy SDK and compiled some examples successfully. But now I down't now how to convert OpenCV Mat to some OpenGL texture. I found some ideas for that conversion, but I did not found any answer where somebody show the needed OpenGL init for this purpose.

Has somebody a good point to start or better some code snipe where I can understand the way to go? (I only need some code to view the image on screen, nothing else)

Best regards
Jürgen